# error @quasar/app@3.0.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module when deploying to Netlify

Tags: node.js, netlify, quasar-framework

I am trying to deploy a Quasar 2 SPA on Netlify, and I'm seeing the following error in my Netlify deploy logs:

```
error @quasar/app@3.0.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">= 12.22.1". Got "12.18.0"
```

The project I'm trying to deploy is here: https://github.com/briancaffey/django-step-by-step

Here are the public build logs that show the error I'm having: https://app.netlify.com/sites/mystifying-ardinghelli-30e1a3/deploys/60f234747a18c63dc054df9e

The Quasar application is in the `quasar-app` directory. I'm using the following deploy settings in my Netlify project:

```
Repository: github.com/briancaffey/django-step-by-step
Base directory: quasar-app
Build command: quasar build -m pwa
Publish directory: quasar-app/dist/pwa
Deploy log visibility: Logs are public
Builds: Active
```

Here are some relevant values from the Quasar project's `package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "quasar": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.0.0-beta.0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.13.14",
    "@quasar/app": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^10.17.15",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.16.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.16.1",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 10 Chrome versions",
    "last 10 Firefox versions",
    "last 4 Edge versions",
    "last 7 Safari versions",
    "last 8 Android versions",
    "last 8 ChromeAndroid versions",
    "last 8 FirefoxAndroid versions",
    "last 10 iOS versions",
    "last 5 Opera versions"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 12.22.1",
    "npm": ">= 6.13.4",
    "yarn": ">= 1.21.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add `NODE_VERSION` to the Netlify settings under Build & Deploy > Environment. I set this variable to 12.22.1 and it built successfully.